# JAVA: Remainder % with printf() not working

Tags: java, printform

I am trying to write the equivalent of

```
System.out.println(a + " % " + b + " = " + r);
```

with the print(f)

```
System.out.printf("%d +'%' + %d = %d",a,b,r);
```

but it says the format string is malformed. I am guessing it is because of the % sign. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for printf formatting?

Comment: Thank you! I will reread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%d %% %d = %d%n", a, b, r);
```

Self-escaped.

Your code constructed a string with a single %.
Also add a newline, by %n which can deliver `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you! It solved it.

Answer (score 1):

% is used as a formate specifier, instead of directly using it you can use it as char.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       int a = 6 ;
       int b = 7;
       int r = 8;
       char chr = '%';
        System.out.printf("%d + %c + %d = %d",a,chr,b,r);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> It should be like that

```
 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a =10;
    int b =5;
    int r =22;

System.out.printf("%d %d %d ",a,b,r);


  }
}
```